# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, tour, 7-questions

The [tour page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tour) states the scope of our site as following:

> **Ethereum Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for users of Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network.

I think this really needs some work. What is the *crypto value* for instance?

What is on-topic? Ethereum, Swarm, Whisper, Blockchain, Consensus, Contracts, DApps? What is Ethereum Stack Exchange about? Looking for proposals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems this could be a community wiki and combining the OP and Hudson's answer:

> **Ethereum Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for users of Ethereum, the smart contract enabled blockchain based consensus network. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Ethereum, its blockchain, smart contracts, decentralized applications, including the Swarm and Whisper protocols.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like:

> Ethereum Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of
>   Ethereum, the smart contract enabled blockchain network. Technical
>   questions about Ethereum are welcomed here. With your help, we're
>   working together to build a library of detailed answers to every
>   question about Ethereum.