# Please change our site's topic!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, topic

This question is a follow up of: [What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/196/87) -- And very important. It's about the `$Topic` of our communty, which is the most basic explaination what Ethereum Stack Exchange is about.

I would like to find consensus about the `$Topic` in this thread. Current topic is:

> Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network

Not sure what the intention of the [early Ethereum proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/89704?phase=definition) was, but especially the part with the *crypto value* causes headache, as it could invite people to post speculative questions about the *value* of Ether or Tokens.

Please find below a suggestion for a new `$Topic`, or post your own.

Comment: I see the flag. I'm not sure if I should choose "no action needed" because we're trying to get a Stack Exchange moderator to update our $Topic, so I will not dismiss the flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be aligned with the [help center](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) / [tour page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tour) to something like:

> Ethereum, the decentralized application platform and smart contract enabled blockchain.

This post is a community wiki. Please edit it for minor fixes. For major changes post another answer.

Comment: This is done, with the caveat that it looked really dumb in the title prompt for /questions/ask (and got cut off), so I shortened it to just "Ethereum" there.

Answer (score 1):

> Ethereum, public blockchain platform with programmable transaction functionality.

It provides a decentralized virtual machine that can execute peer-to-peer contracts using a crypto asset called Ether (unofficial code ETH).

Answer (score 1):

It may take a little time to propagate through all the places, but I'm pleased to report that our site topic, has been fixed, for example see Closing>Off-Topic

> This question does not appear to be about Ethereum, the decentralized
>   application platform and smart contract enabled blockchain, within the
>   scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts so far. Just a note, it's not only about _finding_ a topic, but also about _setting_ it. Only administrators can do that. Edit: oh, it _was already_ set, now I get your post.