# What should our documentation contain?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, 7-questions, meta, documentation

As a follow-up on: [What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/87)

What should our documentation contain? What is our site about and what not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ask about ...

- Specific issues with Ethereum, the smart contract enabled blockchain based consensus network, including Swarm and Whisper protocols
- Specific issues with Solidity, Serpent programming languages and the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM)
- Specific issues with smart contracts, decentralized applications and the web 3.0
- Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

#### Don't ask about ...

- Anything not directly related to the Ethereum, Swarm or Whisper protocols
- Questions that are primarily opinion-based
- Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the second part of the sixth bullet. The length of the answer shouldn't disqualify asking a question. What questions or situations did you have in mind for that rule to apply?

Comment: Actually the points #3, 5, and #6 are Stack Exchange defaults. The 6th is targeted at questions which are considered _too broad_, e.g. "What is Ethereum?"

Comment: Thanks that gives me more clarity. In that context I agree with bullet 6.