# Which question should be included in the Tour page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, topic, tour

many of you noticed that there is an example question [on the tour page](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tour) available to explain new users how the stack exchange site mechanics work using an ethereum specific example.

When I set this question a while back, there was not much to chose from. However, I recently ran a [query on our database](http://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/query/92078/possible-about-questions) and found there are 8 questions available which [meet the requirements for the tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/226837). Here they are:

- [What proof of work function does Ethereum use?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/14/87)
- [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/87)
- [Is there any public Ethereum slack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/408/87)
- [Are there any android wallets for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/835/87)
- [Is there any SPV client for ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/87)
- [Migrating Ethereum development from Windows to Ubuntu](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/87)
- [How are miners minimum acceptable gas price determined?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/87)
- [Where does the consumed ether/gas go?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/87)

Which one do you think fits best? Please explain why it fits best. It should be a question easy understandable by new users and exemplary of quality.

---

While we are at it: See also (and review) related discussions:

- [What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/196/87)
- [Please change our site's topic!](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/202/87)
- [What should our documentation contain?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/204/87)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of great options, but I have to vote for [How can a contract run itself at a later time?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42/how-can-a-contract-run-itself-at-a-later-time). For one, I think it is a short question that most Ethereum newbies would understand and be curious about. Moreover, while the top answer is long, it is an excellent response. Additionally, you can easily find answers to a lot of the other questions by simply reading the Ethereum Yellow paper or solidity docs. In contrast, as far as I know, the question I propose is not answered in any official documentation.